# Asp.Net Model binding is not working for any node that is under "placeholders" using Sitecore ASP.NET Rendering SDK

Tags: layout-service, jss

I am following this https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/model-binding.html to bind my custom model for complex json response from my LayoutService API.

The properties and fields from the Route node are perfectly being populated in the model ComplexComponent but anything that is under "placeholders" node is not being populated and I am getting all properties as null.

Any clue, what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the OOTB code, you can see `index.cshtml`. Here the name of the placeholder is `jss-main`.

[image]

You should be adding the `placeholder Settings` with the same name on the Sitecore page presentation. It will work.